# Redirecting from servlet to GWT place?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-places

There's a GWT application that uses GWT Places/Activities facility. There's also a servlet (currently, not related with GWT by all means) that I need to be able to redirect users to GWT app. Is there a way I can build a Place description in my servlet and then convert it to URL to redirect user to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the GWT app uses generated [PlaceHistoryMapper](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryMapper.html) implementation, then you can build an instance of the place on the server-side and pass it to its `PlaceTokenizer`'s [getToken](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceTokenizer.html#getToken%28P%29) method to get the place-specific token, and append to the tokenizer's [prefix](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/Prefix.html), with a colon (`:`) as a separator.

Otherwise, use the app's place history handler implementation (provided it can be used on the server) and call [getToken](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryMapper.html#getToken%28com.google.gwt.place.shared.Place%29).

Once you have the history token, then if the app uses the [DefaultHistorian](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryHandler.DefaultHistorian.html), then simply use the token as the *hash* of the URL. Otherwise, it'll depend on the app's own historian implementation (for instance, if uses the HTML5 History API, then it probably won't use a `#` in the URL).

Comment: Is there a way to get the prefix value from the Place on the server?

Comment: Use reflection? (get the `@Prefix` from the `PlaceTokenizer`, or use the place's class name)